# Cannot update users with GraphClientService

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

While using newest version of Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Core libraries I am trying to execute following snippet to find user and then update him. User is found and retrieved but after executing Update method, program crashes. The application is .Net Framework 4.6.2. Not possible to upgrade due to other dependencies.

```
var builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "appId",
            ClientSecret = "clientSecret",
            TenantId = "tenantId"
        });

        var client = new GraphServiceClient(
            new MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider(
                builder.Build(), 
                new string[] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }));

        var user = new Microsoft.Graph.User()
        {
            GivenName = "test",
            Surname = "test",
            Mail = "test@testmail.com"                
        };

        var originalUser = await client.Users[upn]
            .Request()
            .Select("displayName")
            .GetAsync();

        await client.Users[originalUser.Id]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(user);
```

Exception message

> {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.","innerError":{"date":"2022-11-04T18:13:06","request-id":"","client-request-id":""}}}

First thoughts are to look at HTTP method used. But this is official distribution from Microsoft running against very slightly customized AzureAd tenant, so I would expect to work just like that. I am starting to be clueless. Gonna be helpful for ideas.

Comment: Is there actually something in originalUser.Id? You are just selecting the displayName.

Comment: This posting has same error indicating the user had PUT instead of POST : https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Specified-HTTP-method-is-not-allowed-for-the-request-target/td-p/631460

Comment: Yeah something along the line happens inside the client. When the id is empty the client presumably does not create a "users/{id}" route to call but only "users" and there you can just GET all users but you can't update (PUT) something there. Misleading error then. Microsoft  should do better Argument checking in its client.

Comment: If you know upn of the user then you can use this upn in update call `await client.Users[upn].Request().UpdateAsync(user);`

Comment: @Ralf you are right. I was precisely that stupid. Write it as answer pls. Gonna mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update user , you have to use

var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(userUpdate);

doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS#updating-an-existing-entity-with-patch

Hope this helps ,

Thanks